# How to backup to s3 as rsync

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to backup my server to s3, but I don't want to upload the entire container every time.

Right now I use s3cmd put --recursive, but that uploads *everything*, and I don't want to waste space and put calls.

What I want to do is to upload all files to s3, and then use s3cmd to put files as rsync would, to upload only updated files.

1. What command should I use
2. What permissions do I have to give?

Answer (score 2):

All answers from Vladimir Mukhin are valid. There is however a tool that can help for 1/ it is called Duplicity.  It takes S3 as a target for backup and does incremental backups. http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html

If you find Duplicity too complex, Duply is a simpler angle to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use several solutions here:

1. Store metadata for uplaoded files (MD5, timestamps, etc.) and check if the file has been modified or not before initiatin upload. There is no special command for this and you need to perfrom additional scripting.
2. Use S3 object versioning. In this case, Amazon will check if a file been modified or not and upload changed files as separate versions. More information here:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/lifecycle-configuration-bucket-with-versioning.html
3. Use awscli (https://aws.amazon.com/cli/). With this you can run `aws s3 sync ...`, which will only upload changes.

Answer (score 0):

[rclone](https://rclone.org/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I still do not understand whether it uploads just the delta of the changes  @keith Please let understand that